# how can avoid server rendering of some components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and what i'm trying to know is how can i avoid server rendering of some components.
here is my code:

```
export default class PrTopBanner extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.isTextVisible = false;
   }

   componentDidMount() {
    this.isTextVisible = true;
   }

   getContent() {
     return (
       <div>
         <a className={classNames(cssClasses.textWrapper, {
            'textVisible': this.isTextVisible})}
         </a>
       </div>
     );
   }    
}
```

The text content invisible, and fades in componentDidMount(), so how can avoid that my code regarding text won't be have a server rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Few issues - you need to call render() not getContent() is one. This works:

```js
class PrTopBanner extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.isTextVisible = false;
   }

   componentDidMount() {
    this.isTextVisible = true;
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <a className='test'>test
         </a>
       </div>
     );
   }    
}

ReactDOM.render(<PrTopBanner />, document.querySelector('#container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```